# How to change or set new activity launcher app? (in Java)

Tags: java, android

I have a payment activity and splash activity that it shows app of contents after user will buy it. payment activity is default Launcher in Manifest.xml that I want to set launcher Activity to  splash activity and payment activity disabled after payment.

Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.exa.iu2">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>

    <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".PaymentActivity" android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <data android:scheme="return" android:host=“zrp”/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
            <activity-alias
                android:name=".PaymentActivity"
                android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
                android:enabled="false"                              android:targetActivity=".SplashActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity-alias>
        <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

in Payment Activity and "If payment is success"

```
public void onCallbackResultVerificationPayment(boolean isPaymentSuccess, String refID, PaymentRequest paymentRequest) {
        if(isPaymentSuccess){
            Toast.makeText(PaymentActivity.this, “Payment Success” + refID, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            ComponentName cm = new ComponentName("com.exa.iu2", "com.exa.iu2"+".SplashActivity");
            ComponentName cm2 = new ComponentName("com.exa.iu2", "com.exa.iu2"+".PaymentActivity");
            PackageManager pm = getApplication().getPackageManager();
            pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(cm, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
            pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(cm2, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,0);
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(PaymentActivity.this, “Don’t success”, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        }
    });
```

Thx

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create a Hub or Startup activity in which decide what to display. The new activity has to be set as Main -> Launcher activity, obviously.

Comment: May you give some information about Hub or Startup Activity?

Comment: It is a simple Activity where you can put whatever business logic you need to display the Splash activity or the Payment activity.

Comment: As you say, I dont need <activity-alias> and check  my condition with third activity that it is success to start splash activity otherwise start payment activity

Answer (score 0):

In `AndroidManifest` do this

```
<activity android:name=".SplashActivity"
          android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Inside `SplashActivity`

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Check condition to open appropriate activity
        // like 
        // if(paymentDone) start some activity
        // else start another activity 

        finish()

    }
}
```